# Lambda times out after 3 sec

Tags: aws-lambda

Lambda runs and times out after 3 seconds causing my script to make 3 snapshots instead of one. Then it does not continue with the rest of the script. When I run the script on an ec2 instance, then script works fine. I was also wondering would it be better to separate this script into two scripts.

```
import boto3
from datetime import date


SOURCE_REGION = 'us-east-1'
DEST_REGION = 'us-west-2'


ec2_source      = boto3.client('ec2', region_name = SOURCE_REGION, config=Config(connect_timeout=5, read_timeout=60, retries={'max_attempts': 2}))
ec2_destination = boto3.client('ec2', region_name = DEST_REGION, config=Config(connect_timeout=5, read_timeout=60, retries={'max_attempts': 2}))

def lambda_handler(event, context):


   volumes = ec2_source.describe_volumes(Filters=[{'Name':'tag:Backup','Values':['Yes']}])['Volumes']

   for volume in volumes:
      print('Getting:', volume['VolumeId'])
      response = ec2_source.create_snapshot(
         Description = 'Prod_' + volume['VolumeId'],
         VolumeId = volume['VolumeId'],
      )
      SourceVolumeID = response['SnapshotId']
      ec2_source.create_tags(Resources=[SourceVolumeID],
           Tags=volume['Tags']
      )
      SourceTagID = response['SnapshotId']
      ec2_source.delete_tags(Resources=[SourceTagID],
           Tags=[ {'Key': 'Backup', 'Value': 'Yes' },]
      )
      SourceTagID = response['SnapshotId']
      ec2_source.create_tags(Resources=[SourceTagID],
           Tags=[ {'Key': 'Backup', 'Value': 'Complete' },]
      )
      SourceTagID = response['SnapshotId']
      ec2_source.create_tags(Resources=[SourceTagID],
           Tags=[ {'Key': 'Done', 'Value': 'Copied' },]
      )

   try:

      waiter = ec2_source.get_waiter('snapshot_completed')
      waiter.wait(
           SnapshotIds=[SourceTagID],
           DryRun=False,
           WaiterConfig={'Delay': 10,'MaxAttempts': 123}
      )

   except botocore.exceptions.WaiterError as e:
                print(e.message)

   snaps = ec2_source.describe_snapshots(OwnerIds=['self'], Filters=[{'Name':'tag:Backup','Values':['Complete']}])['Snapshots']

   Tday       = date.today()
   Tday_snaps = [ s for s in snaps if s['StartTime'].date() == Tday ]

   for Tday_s in Tday_snaps:
          print('Copying:', Tday_s['SnapshotId'])
          DestinationSnapshot = ec2_destination.copy_snapshot(
              SourceSnapshotId = Tday_s['SnapshotId'],
              SourceRegion = SOURCE_REGION,
              Description = Tday_s['VolumeId']
          )
          DestinationTagID = DestinationSnapshot['SnapshotId']
          ec2_destination.create_tags(Resources=[DestinationTagID],
              Tags=Tday_s['Tags']
          )
          DestinationTagID = DestinationSnapshot['SnapshotId']
          ec2_destination.delete_tags(Resources=[DestinationTagID],
              Tags=[ {'Key': 'Backup', 'Value': 'Complete' },]
          )
```

Answer (score 1):

The default timeout for a Lambda is 3 seconds.  To update, go to the Lambda console and select your Lambda.  Then scroll down a bit to "Basic Settings".  Select that:

[image]

And update as you need.

If you're using the `aws` cli, you can run something like:

```
aws lambda update-function-configuration --function-name functionName --timeout 45
```

to change the Lambda function `functionName` to have a 45 second timeout.